# How can I Implement hero carousel used in gettyimages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to use a similar carousel to the one that gettyimages.com uses. I have inspected the element and found that they have used something called "hero carousel".

Any guidance for this exact carousel is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like http://jquery-plugins.net/hero-carousel-jquery-carousel-plugin-with-100-percent-width might be what you're after?

Comment: I went through this but could find similar carousal

Comment: Look here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ I think you can get the same carousel using this.